# viewStack.addChild adding multiple child and only the last child is visible!

Tags: apache-flex, viewstack

```
var viewStack:ViewStack = new ViewStack();
viewStack.percentWidth = 100;
viewStack.percentHeight = 100;
viewStack.addChild(canVas1);
viewStack.addChild(canVas2);
viewStack.addChild(canVas3);
lb = new LinkBar();
lb.dataProvider=viewStack;
```

Its only displaying canVas3 contents not canVas1 and canVas2

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what it's supposed to do.  It just puts components one on top of the other like a deck of cards, with the topmost (last added) being visible.  Check [this](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/ViewStack) out.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I know its shows in the form of deck, but when you addChild let say Area1, Area2 and Area3 its showing me only Area3 and nothing in Area1 and Area2.

Comment: To see the other areas, you need to change the selected index on the viewstack.  Look at the example I linked in the answer.  You can only see one of the areas at a time.

Comment: Hey SB, Can you please send the link again I dont see it in answer.

Comment: I am trying to do it in ActionScript, the viewstack is a dataprovider to linkBar, and viewstack has multiple canvas and only the last is visible.Am I missing something to add in here.
Where would I add viewStack.selectIndex?
var   canV_brand:Canvas = new Canvas();
    canV_brand.label = "Canvas1";
    canV_brand.addChild(hBox1);
Same viewstack I mention in the question earlier

Comment: try viewStack.selectedIndex=1; in your code - you can change it to whatever you want depending on which one you want to see.  YOU CAN ONLY SEE ONE AT A TIME

Comment: The thing is I do see the canvas3, but not canvas1 and canvas2 when I click on there respective linkbutton. for eg: not able to see Area1 and Area2 when I click there respective button.
I know only one panel will be visible at a time, but I am only able to see the top most, not the first and second.